# Client sender failed to send response message - ECM Documentum

Tags: java, documentum, ecm, connectexception

I gets the following error while openning any MS doccument from WebTop and  as the  reuslt I nothing can open... :(

```
Jan 23, 2013 6:26:32 AM com.documentum.ucf.client.logging.impl.UCFLogger warn
WARNING: UCF Client Version 5.3.0.1
Jan 23, 2013 6:26:37 AM com.documentum.ucf.client.logging.impl.UCFLogger fatal
SEVERE: Client sender failed to send response message
com.documentum.ucf.common.transport.TransportStreamException: Client sender failed to send response message
    at com.documentum.ucf.client.transport.impl.ClientSender.send(ClientSender.java:74)
    at com.documentum.ucf.client.transport.impl.ClientSession.sendAndGetReceiver(ClientSession.java:590)
    at com.documentum.ucf.client.transport.impl.ClientSession.handshake(ClientSession.java:673)
    at com.documentum.ucf.client.transport.impl.ClientSession.handshake(ClientSession.java:653)
    at com.documentum.ucf.client.transport.impl.ClientSession.run(ClientSession.java:270)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.ucf.client.transport.impl.ClientNativeGAIRConnector.sendProlog(ClientNativeGAIRConnector.java:179)
    at com.documentum.ucf.client.transport.impl.ClientSender.send(ClientSender.java:46)
    ... 4 more
```

Can't  understand why the connection is refused. 
I uses Windows 7 x64 , ECM Documentum 6.7 for , IE 8(for 32 and 64)/ IE9 (for 32 and 64), java 1.6.  Is  anybody can help  me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I installed  the  latest  WebLogic version anf  the  error  has  gone.

Cheers!